# Advantages using the Yeoman .net core spa Angular template to create an Angular MVC project if API is a separate project?

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, yeoman, asp.net-core-webapi

I created a typical N-Tier architecture solution with project called TestProj.Api, TestProj.Business, TestProj.Data. All 3 of these projects work great together in VS2017.

Then I added a fourth project using the Yeoman Angular .Net Core Spa Template: TestProj.Web. This project makes api calls to TestProj.Api with CORS. I currently run multiple solution startup projects: TestProj.Api and TestProj.Web.

I am starting to notice that I like developing Angular in VSCode and additionally not sure if I like the Angular ASP.NET Core Template. I am wondering if TestProj.Web should be created outside of my solution.

What are the true advantages of using this Angular Template, here are the ones I can think of:
1. Able to keep everything in same VS2017 solution. Api, Business, Data, Web
2. Able to have a server-side Api and Angular in the same project (which I am not taking advantage of since I want my API to be completely separate)

Is there anything else I am not thinking of? Is there any suggestions on what I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your point number (2) really answers your own question:

2. Able to have a server-side Api and Angular in the same project (which I am not taking advantage of since I want my API to be completely separate)

As you are intimating, they are not the same projects. They will have different release schedules, different coding styles/languages, etc. Since they are separate projects , really, then managing them using different IDEs becomes less of a worry.

In fact I, like you, started trying to use Visual Studio to manage the API as well as the web front end. However I soon found out that Visual Studio is BAD at managing the Angular 2 front-end stuff. VS Code plus a command line window is far, far easier. Its just more suited to the task. Trying to get Visual Studio to do this is like trying to get a car to be a boat - it never really works properly.

Having been through the same decision process as yourself, and having seen how much easier it is to manage the web code using VS Code and command prompt, I would strongly recommend to ditch Visual Studio for the front end.

For the back end API, Visual Studio is very strong.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. So I should just use the Angular CLI to create an Angular 4 project inside of the same projects workspace to at least keep everything proper in source control right? I use Visual Studio Team Services for Source Control.

Comment: Yeah use the Angular CLI to create the project. I am not familiar with VSTS but see no reason you can't add the Angular source files to source control.

A tip, however. Don't add the "node_modules" directory to source control as it will contain tens of thousands of files. The contents of this dir are maintained by npm and can be recreated at any time from your package.json

Comment: If this was helpful please consider marking as answer such that others can find it more easily